# Scheduled scan for wpa_supplicant daemon

Tags: linux, android-wifi, wpa, wifi

I want to know how to stop the scheduled scans of wpa_supplicant daemon?

Is it possible to stop scanning which is done by wpa_supplicant periodically?
Can it be done by any commands or parameters of daemon upon startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wpa_cli set pno.
wpa_cli is the control interface for wpa_supplicant, pno is standing for Profile Network Offload. If you are running it with a parameter after pno it will start scheduled scan, otherwise it will stop it. This command will stop user initiated sched scan; to stop autoamtic one try wpa_cli disconnect.